# A fair die is rolled five times.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, dice

An ordinary fair die is thrown five times. If $P=\frac{a}{b}$ expressed in lowest form is the probability that the outcome of the fifth throw was already thrown, then find the value of $(a + b)$.

Below given is my approach and the original solution to this question.  Can anyone figure it out where am I wrong?

My Approach

[image: My approach]

Original Solution
[image: Original Solution]

Comment: I upvoted because you showed good work and because you nicely embedded a picture into your query.  However, I couldn't attack your problem because I couldn't decipher your work.  I would like to offer formatting suggestions for future reference: (1) See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.  This link will explain using mathjax to implant formatted math directly into your query.  ...See next comment.

Comment: (2) I think it is asking a lot of a new user to use computer software for a picture to be imbedded, rather than your method of simply scanning your page of work.  So your method is reasonable.  However, whichever way you choose (mathjax, scanned page, or computer software) to present work, please try to make the work that you want critiqued to be **crystal clear.**  I (for one) had trouble deciphering your reasoning, which meant that I (for one) couldn't point out where you went wrong.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the suggestion, i will try to use mathjax in my questions. Also,  now onwards I will make my work crystal clear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is duplication issue here.

Consider the following two cases:

($1$) You choose the first throw to be the same as $5$th throw, and the second throw happens to be the same as well.

($2$) You choose the second throw to be the same as $5$th throw, and the first throw happens to be the same as well.

They are essentially the same case but you have double counted these two cases.

Comment: Then is there any other method to do this question apart from the original Solution?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate all the cases where exactly $1$ throw matches, exactly $2$ throws matches, exactly $3$ throw matches and so on and add them up, albeit the original solution is definitely the shortest.

Comment: Ok thanks......